# Is it possible to separate Controller and View in RESTful Symfony app?

Tags: php, api, rest, symfony, model-view-controller

I am thinking about using Symfony to create a RESTful api. I want my app to only accept json and/or xml and just output either. I want my frontend to be completely separate in a separate directory.

Disclaimer: I know most frameworks only claim to be MVC, and that the definition/principles of MVC vary from developer to developer. Therefore, I've laid out my understanding of MVC.

How I picture MVC (taken from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)):

[image: Essential dependencies between model, view, and controller. (I call this essential because in fact the view and controller do link to each other directly, but developers mostly don't use this fact.)]

- Make a strong separation between presentation (view & controller) and domain (model)
- Controller and view should (mostly) not communicate directly but through the model.
- Have views (and controllers) observe the model to allow multiple widgets to update without needed to communicate directly - Observer Synchronization.

In Symfony, the Controller returns a Response, and there really isn't a View class. They sort of combined the two.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to separate the controller into a controller and view?
- Can you make the controller not return something?
- Possible to not have any html/templates within the app/bundle?

  - As I stated earlier, I want to keep frontend completely separate, therefore, I wouldn't use twig. I would use JS, SASS, React, etc. for my frontend stuff to make ajax calls to my Symfony api.

Comment: "Can you make the controller not return something?" --- how would caller know if the request was accepted then?

Comment: Symfony does support views via an event: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-view.  However, I think you are over engineering things.  Unless you have a really good reason then just have the controller return a json response.

Comment: As @Cerad said, you can return some "data" from the controller and use a listener on the kernel.view to turn this into a representation. The FOSRestBundle does this, as an example (but you can implement this yourself). You do not need any templates if you're only building an API.

Comment: @zerkms I don't know much about Symfony, so I can't rightly answer that. How I've done it in the past is not have the controller return something, and have the view be called the same as the controller (by using the uri) and then having the view call the model for the necessary data that was loaded (or not) by the controller reacting to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a pretty standard architecture.

You do not need to use templates but your controllers have to return "something". If you are handling the view in the front-end, this would be just the data needed to create this view, usually in the form of json

Symfony can do this, no problem